# Error llamando View específico de StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Estoy tratando de llamar un view del story board con el siguiente codigo pero me sale el error `as no segue with identifier`

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```
dispatch_async ( dispatch_get_main_queue ())  {
 [ unowned self ]  in
 self . performSegueWithIdentifier ( "WelcomeController" , sender :  self )
}
```

Comment: No te puedo contestar ya que no tengo ni idea de swift, xcode o iOS, pero si entiendes ingles lo suficiente, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874200/nsinvalidargumentexception-receiver-has-no-segue-with-identifier parece hablar de lo mismo

Comment: tu codigo tiene esos espacios de pusiste aqui??

Answer (score 0):

Revisá en el `storyboard`, el identificador del `segue`que estás utilizando. Por lo que dice el error, no existe un `segue` con el `id` que estás utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que el segue este conectado con ese ViewController y que efectivamente tenga el identifier "WelcomeController"

Answer (score 0):

Igual me equivoco, pero creo que estás confundiendo el `segue` con el `storyboard identifier`. El segue te permite ir de un controlador a otro con o sin animación. El `storyboard identifier` es un identificador único dentro del storyboard para cada controlador.

Si lo que tratas de hacer es una animación de un controlador a otro, el método que usas es correcto y tendrías que verificar que efectivamente exista dentro del storyboard un controlador con el identificador `WelcomeController`.

Si lo que tratas de hacer es instanciar un controlador para usarlo dentro del código, tienes que usar:

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeController"];
```

Y en el puntero `controller` tendrás la instancia.